# Inserting items to vector by value vs unique_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

I wonder what's the difference in performance and memory consumption between these two declarations of vector.

```
class MyType;
std::vector<MyType> vectorA;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> vectorB;
```

I have a dilemma, since I have to create some observers into the vector and if I'm doing that while initializing, I have to use unique_ptrs because of the vector's variable size. I don't want to use shared_ptrs because they have big memory overhead.
 
I'm looking for the best trade-off between performance and memory consumption. 
I need to know if it's better to init vectorA first (after initialization it's strictly immutable) and then create observers into that vector (it won't be changing its content so I can do that). In this scenario I would lose some performance.
Or if it is better to create vectorB instead of vectorA. Then I would be able to create observers while initialization, since the location that the unique_ptr is pointing to won't be changed. I suppose that in this case I would lose at least 4B/8B per item.
What do the best practices say? I'm beginner with C++ and I'm solving such a problem for the first time.

Comment: Where did you read that shared pointers have big memory overhead?

Comment: I have tried them in my project and then I tried to switch to unique_ptrs with observers. With shared_ptrs my program was consuming sth about 250 MB RAM and with unique_ptrs only 160 MB RAM. I think that's big memory overhead. Size of my vector is something about 2,1 mil. items so I think it really matters.

Comment: Control block of shared pointer takes memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would go with `std::vector<MyType>`.

The advantages of the approach are:

- A single memory block containing all elements, so looping over it will better as the prefetcher can work better
- Less memory allocations as new/delete are expensive methods
- Less memory overhead (however, does 1 extra pointer per element do that much? You might gain this by ordering your members to reduce padding)
- Pointers to elements are stable until you realloc (so reserving in front with the correct size can give stable pointers if you never push_back more than reserved)

However, using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>>` resolves a few of the negative elements:

- Can be used with MyType being an abstract class (or interface)
- Move/copy constructor of the class will not be called (which can be expensive or non-existent)
- It will allow you to keep raw pointers to MyType

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, explained everything!